# Find area fill of 1 in a bool matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, polygon

[image]

i have a bool matrix, i wanna find area(s) that fill of 1(true value). the area represent as polygon(clock wise).

can somebody give me an idea.

Comment: Flooding. Start at the top left, find the first `1` entry; iteratively flood from that point on, meaning: consider the cell to the left, right, top, bottom of your `1` entry and check whether that is also `1`. Once you don't find another such cell, that block is full; find the next `1` in the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The union-find algorithm is an excellent approach to find connected sub-graphs (or regions in this case). It's also a linear complexity algorithm so it's basically as good as BFS :)

http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Union_Find

Answer (score 1):

You could use **BFS search method** to solve the problem, or **Flood-Fill** algorithm to solve the problem

Or so you can use **DFS** to solve this problem if you like to use recurve